# Calling C function with pointers from F#

Tags: .net, f#

I'm new to F# and trying to communicate with a C-library from F#. I'm able to use several of the functions it provides but the Read() function is proving tricky since it has two parameters which are pointer and return the read content.

Here is the C function definition:

```
TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_Read(
        TPCANHandle Channel, 
        TPCANMsg* MessageBuffer, 
        TPCANTimestamp* TimestampBuffer);
```

And here is the C# definition:

```
        [DllImport("PCANBasic.dll", EntryPoint = "CAN_Read")]
        public static extern TPCANStatus Read(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
            TPCANHandle Channel,
            out TPCANMsg MessageBuffer,
            out TPCANTimestamp TimestampBuffer);
```

And here is the F# version I'm working on:

```
module PCANBasic =
    type TPCANHandle = uint16

    [<Struct>]
    type TPCANTimestamp =
        val millis : uint32
        val millisOverflow : uint16
        val micros : uint16
        new (_millis, _overflow, _micros) = {millis = _millis; millisOverflow = _overflow; micros = _micros}

    [<Struct>]
    type TPCANMsg =
        val mutable id : uint32
        [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)>]
        val mutable mstype : byte
        val mutable len : byte
        [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)>]
        val mutable data : byte array
        new (_id, _mstype, _len, _data) = {id = _id; mstype = _mstype; len = _len; data = _data}
        new (_id, _data) = {id = _id; mstype = 0x00uy; len = byte (Array.length _data); data = Array.concat [| _data; (Array.zeroCreate 8) |]}

    module private Imported =
        [<DllImport("PCANBasic.dll", EntryPoint="CAN_Read")>]
        extern TPCANStatus Read(
                [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)>]
                TPCANHandle Channel,
                [<Out>]
                TPCANMsg MessageBuffer,
                [<Out>]
                TPCANTimestamp TimestampBuffer)

    let read (chan : TPCANHandle, [<Out>] msgbuf : TPCANMsg byref, [<Out>] tsbuf : TPCANTimestamp byref) = 
        Imported.Read(chan, msgbuf, tsbuf)
```

```
let main argv =
    ….
     let mbuf = ref (PCANBasic.TPCANMsg(0x010u, Array.zeroCreate 8))
     let tbuf = ref (PCANBasic.TPCANTimestamp(0u,0us,0us))
     let status = PCANBasic.read(handle, mbuf, tbuf)           //Error here
```

The last line shows an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'byref<PCANBasic.TPCANMsg>'    
but here has type
    'PCANBasic.TPCANMsg ref'    CANTestApp  C:\Users\source\repos\CANTestApp\CANTestApp\Program.fs  189 Active
```

How can I correctly call this C function with pointers from F#? Do you need the `[<Out>]` attribute when you use `byref`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of options for this.

## Option #1

Create a `byref` or `outref` rather than a `ref` by binding `mbuf` and `tbuf` as mutable values and then passing them "by reference" using `&`.

```ml
let main argv =
    ...
    let mutable mbuf = PCANBasic.TPCANMsg(0x010u, Array.zeroCreate 8)
    let mutable tbuf = PCANBasic.TPCANTimestamp(0u,0us,0us)
    let status = PCANBasic.read(handle, &mbuf, &tbuf)
```

## Option #2

Define `read` as a member rather than a function to allow it to be invoked with `ref` arguments rather than `byref`. Your `main` function can then stay the same other than referencing the static `Reader.Read` method rather than the `read` function.

```ml
type Reader =
    static member Read (chan : TPCANHandle, [<Out>] msgbuf : TPCANMsg byref, [<Out>] tsbuf : TPCANTimestamp byref) =
        Imported.Read(chan, msgbuf, tsbuf)
```

## `[<Out>]` Attribute

Looking at [F# RFC FS-1053](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.5/FS-1053-span.md#interoperability) indicates that a `byref<T>` argument with the `[<Out>]` attribute is equivalent to an `outref<T>` argument, so your `read` function/member definition could be (slightly) shortened to:

```ml
let read (chan : TPCANHandle, msgbuf : TPCANMsg outref, tsbuf : TPCANTimestamp outref) =
    Imported.Read(chan, msgbuf, tsbuf)
```

Comment: I tried option #1, and this got rid of the error I saw but mbuf does not contain the data expected after the function call.

Comment: Ah, I think the `[<Out>]` arguments in your `extern` definition need to include `&`, i.e. `TPCANMsg& MessageBuffer` and `TPCANTimestamp& TimestampBuffer`

Comment: Still not getting the expected data after the function call. I've noticed the function returns immediately rather that pausing for input. Could this be due to the initial values in `mbuf`?

Comment: Only thing I can suggest without seeing more of the C# implementation is to check that the structures are defined correctly (field names, field types, etc.). The `TPCANMsg` constructor you're using looks slightly suspect as well, since you're concatenating the input array with another array of length 8 and then assigning to a field that should only have a total length of 8.

Comment: The field types look ok, but you'll need to update the field names so that they match the C# fields exactly, otherwise the C implementation will not be able to reference them properly.

Comment: I'm updated the filed names in TPCANMsg to match that in the C# field but still no luck. I'm not confident that's the issue as all along I'm been able write/transmit data, just not able to read/receive data. The mbuf structure is always zero.